# JSP Login user roles

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I have one page with JSP forms that contains upload and delete button which is the primary or only role of the admin users. If the login user is not admin I dont want any user to have access for that, I tried but I can not find any solution can someone help me.

Comment: Can you give more details about the structure of the form and your login system, especially how you determine if a user is admin. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried with mysql to define admin and user and connected to DB of netbeans but what I really would like to do is to give just admin the permission to add or upload not the other one. I am new in this and I really do not know how to do it

Comment: So you want to show/hide control elements based on user roles. You need to explain how both the controls and the users are defined. Without that it is difficult to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Spring, you can guard your buttons with [`sec:authorize`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/taglibs.html#taglibs-authorize):

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('admin')">
    <button>Delete</button>
</sec:authorize>
```

If you don't use Spring you can use JSTL's `c:if`, but in that case you'll need to expose roles in JSP somehow, e.g. in `session`:

```
<c:if test="${sessionScope.user.role == 'admin'}">
    <button>Delete</button>
</c:if>
```

Comment: I am using Netbeans with Java Web ... Can you give me some hints? I searched but I can not find any solution. the idea was to create a login with access of admin and user. where I should use the same page created but admin will be allowed to upload photo and files in website, and user just be a guest.

Comment: Netbeans has nothing to do with JSPs, it's just and IDE, an editor you use to author the code. Java Web? What is that? Do you mean that you don't use any kind of framework, like Spring / Struts / Play, just plain old servlets and JSP? If that is the case, just use [JSTL taglib](https://jstl.java.net/) and `c:if` tag.